# Transition to new data upon clickEvent

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I am using code that creates horizontal bar charts, that I have accessed form [here](http://hdnrnzk.me/2012/07/04/creating-a-bar-graph-using-d3js/) and modified a little to fit my needs.

I am looking to transition to a new dataset upon clicking on one of the bars.

For example, if someone were to click on America, I want to render a new graph that has american state names and their values.

Here's the initial dataset

```
var countries = ['India', 'America', 'China', 'Russia', 'London'],
    value = [8, 4, 9, 12, 11];
```

And here's what I want it to transition to upon click on America or the 4 bar

```
var AmericaS = ['MA','CA','NH'],
AmericaV = [10,9,11];
```

Here's the jsfiddle with the code I have so far:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6HVmk/)

I have been trying out different ways to do this, but nothing seems to be working. I would really appreciate any help you could give me.

Comment: Did you have a look at [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I understand the redraw function would render a new graph, with the updated data. However, I guess my main issue is I don't know how to transition from one data set to another. I don't know how to reset the parameter in .data(...)

Comment: You don't need to reset anything. You simply pass in the new data and handle the enter, update and exit selections. In your case, the update selection would be empty, the enter selection would contain all the elements of the new data set and the exit selection everything in the old data set (with an appropriate matching function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [M.Bostocks' example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/bar-hierarchy.html) which is similar to what your trying to do if I am correct. Take a look at the page source the code for drawing the graph.

In case you wanted an example of the data that is been passed though -

```
var demoArray = {
    "name" : "aa",
    "children" : [{
        "name" : "analytics",
        "children" : [{
            "name" : "cluster",
            "children" : [{
                "test" : 'aaa',
                "name" : "AgglomerativeCluster",
                "size" : 3938
            }, {
                "test" : 'aaa',
                "name" : "CommunityStructure",
                "size" : 3812
            }, {
                "test" : 'aaa',
                "name" : "MergeEdge",
                "size" : 743
            }]
        }, {
            "name" : "graph",
            "children" : [{
                "test" : 'aaa',
                "name" : "BetweennessCentrality",
                "size" : 3534
            }, {
                "test" : 'aaa',
                "name" : "LinkDistance",
                "size" : 5731
            }]
        }]
    }]
};
```

Replace line 72-76 of the page source code to look like this,

```
hierarchy.nodes(demoArray);
x.domain([0, demoArray.value]).nice();
down(demoArray, 0);
```

or just put it into a the JSON array.

Hopefully this will help you, if not apologies :D

Comment: Thanks, it was of great help :)